# Generate Entites in the Silex Framework

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am new in *Silex* framework. But I have knowledge about *Symfony* framework. I want to generate an Entity in Silex like in Symfony framework. For Symfony we run this:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MusicBox
```

But how can I create an entity in Silex? I have setup all things like doctrine etc.

Comment: Read documentation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html

Comment: There is no console command in silex to generate entities. As pointed by @malcolm, you should use the doctrine commands directly (or stick with Symfony if you really need the whole ORM)

Answer (score 1):

First of all add Doctrine ORM provider

https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider

Then create console.php with doctrine commands.

This my Doctrine console file, change it for you needs.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
$app = new App\Application();
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

$console = new Application();
$app->boot();
$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($app['db']),
    'dialog' => new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper(),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($app['db.orm.em'])
]);
$console->setHelperSet($helperSet);
$console->addCommands([
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\ExecuteCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\StatusCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\VersionCommand(),
    // DBAL Commands
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\RunSqlCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ImportCommand(),
    // ORM Commands
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\MetadataCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\ResultCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\QueryCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\CreateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\DropCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\EnsureProductionSettingsCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ConvertDoctrine1SchemaCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateRepositoriesCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateEntitiesCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateProxiesCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ConvertMappingCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\RunDqlCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ValidateSchemaCommand(),
]);
$console->run();
```